# Why IEGetProtectedModeCookie() always return 0x80070057?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, cookies, internet-explorer-8

According the function description in "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196998%28v=VS.85%29.aspx", I wrote the following code to try to get IE protected cookies:

```
public static string GetProtectedModeCookie(string lpszURL, string lpszCookieName, uint dwFlags)
{
    var size = 255;
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(size);
    var acturalSize = sb.Capacity;
    var code = IEGetProtectedModeCookie(lpszURL, lpszCookieName, sb, ref acturalSize, dwFlags);
    if ((code & 0x80000000) > 0) return string.Empty;
    if (acturalSize > size)
    {
        sb.EnsureCapacity(acturalSize);
        IEGetProtectedModeCookie(lpszURL, lpszCookieName, sb, ref acturalSize, dwFlags);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

[DllImport("ieframe.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint IEGetProtectedModeCookie(string lpszURL, string lpszCookieName, System.Text.StringBuilder pszCookieData, ref int pcchCookieData, int dwFlags);
```

to test this function:

```
var cookies = GetProtectedModeCookie("http://bbs.pcbeta.com/", null, 0);
```

But the api **IEGetProtectedModeCookie** always return ***0x80070057*** which indicates that one or more arguments are invalid.
I was confused, after a lot of try finally failed, only get this result. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IEGetProtectedModeCookie will return E_INVALIDARG if it thinks that the URL isn't meant to open in Protected Mode. It determines this using the [IEIsProtectedModeURL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. So if you've put that URL in the Trusted Zone or whatnot, then you'll hit this error. The underlying InternetGetCookie API will return E_INVALIDARG if you fail to pass a URL or fail to pass a pointer to an integer for the size of the buffer.

Also note that the IEGetProtectedModeCookie API will not work from a high integrity (e.g. Admin) process; it will return ERROR_INVALID_ACCESS (0x8000000C).

Here's the code I use:

```
[DllImport("ieframe.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "IEGetProtectedModeCookie", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int IEGetProtectedModeCookie(String url, String cookieName, StringBuilder cookieData, ref int size, uint flag);


private void GetCookie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int iSize = 4096;
    StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder(iSize);

    int hResult = IEAPI.IEGetProtectedModeCookie("http://www.google.com", "PREF", sbValue, ref iSize, 0);

    if (hResult == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sbValue.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to get cookie. HRESULT=0x" + hResult.ToString("x") + "\nLast Win32Error=" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString(), "Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I've open IE process mode, and navigated to the destination website.
The cookies in protected mode can be found under 'AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low'
But this api still returns 0x80070057.

I'm also trying to use IEIsProtectedModeURL:

    [DllImport("ieframe.dll")]
    public static extern HRESULT IEIsProtectedModeURL(string pszUrl);

But it also returns 0x80070057 with this call:

    IsProtectedModeURL("http://www.pcbeta.com/");

I wonder what's the possibly cause?
Many thanks.

Comment: I've got the reason....I missed the Charset in DllImport attribute. After I added ", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode" to the DllImport attribte, this api works well. Thanks for your help, I've got the tip from your code :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Charset** parameter must be exist in **DllImport** attribute. Change the API declartion to follow will works well:

```
[DllImport("ieframe.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint IEGetProtectedModeCookie(string lpszURL, string lpszCookieName, System.Text.StringBuilder pszCookieData, ref int pcchCookieData, uint dwFlags);
```

If **Charset** parameter missed, this API will always return ***0x80070057*** which indicates one or more arguments are invalid.