# Why I got overflow error when I do this:

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim strMyNull As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Dim strCkUrl As String = "http://google.com"
Dim strCkNmNull As New System.Text.StringBuilder
Dim mystr As String = Space(192)
Dim strBuffer As New System.Text.StringBuilder(mystr)
strBuffer = strBuffer.Append(mystr)
Dim CkSz As Integer = Len(mystr)
Dim lReturn As Integer = 0


lReturn = ias.IEGetProtectedModeCookie(strCkUrl, vbNullString, strBuffer, CkSz, 0)
```

ias.IEGetProtectedModeCookie is declared here:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ieframe.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)> _
Public Function IEGetProtectedModeCookie(lpszURL As String, lpszCookieName As String, pszCookieData As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByRef pcchCookieData As Integer, dwFlags As UInteger) As UInteger
End Function
```

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346565/why-iegetprotectedmodecookie-always-return-0x80070057

Comment: I have read that. I am using solution from that question. Before it does give different error. Now it throws overflow exception.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of IEGetProtectedModeCookie() is declared as **UInteger**, but you have declared lReturn as **Integer**.

UInteger = 0 through 4,294,967,295

Integer = -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647

The actual return value of IEGetProtectedModeCookie needs to be Integer.

so change the function declaration to:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ieframe.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)> _
Public Function IEGetProtectedModeCookie(lpszURL As String, lpszCookieName As String, pszCookieData As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByRef pcchCookieData As Integer, dwFlags As UInteger) As Integer
End Function
```

Comment: integer in .net is long in vb6. How many bytes are there? integer is 32 bits right?

Comment: Integer in VB6 is 2 bytes, Integer/UInteger in .NET are 4 bytes.

Comment: so should I change that to lReturn as Long?